# Template usage based on category

Tags: templates, categories

Is it possible to use particular template group based on a category of landing page? For an example product categorized as furniture will load template from furniture template group (index) instead of user will go to Pages -> Templates and choose it from a drop down.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it myself, but [Router](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/router) looks to be what you need to use.

Comment: Interesting add-on. Thanks!